# My Samsung Galaxy S4 was stolen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

My Samsung Galaxy S4 was stolen and doesn't have a lock. It was deactivated but I'm worried about the fact that whoever has the phone has access to everything from pictures, videos, my Facebook, contacts, etc. The phone's been deactivated but what can I do about the pictures on the phone? I have a 4 year old daughter and I'm afraid of the pictures on there falling into the wrong hands...I have no other accounts set up to help with privacy but would really like the phone tracked or wiped out...Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to erase the device from Andriod Device manager at

http://www.android.com/devicemanager

Note that this will work only if:

1. The phone has your account still logged in
2. The phone is connected to the internet at the time of sending the erase request or after. [Wifi or Mobile Network]
3. the new user hasn't reset the device.